# AppStart vs static constructor in ASP.NET WebPages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I have a static class in my `App_Code` folder:

```
public static class SiteData
{
    public static string AdminEmail{ get; set; }
}
```

The class could have static members which will be shared among users. In this example, I used `AdminEmail`.

I know two ways of initializing the `AdminEmail`:

**Solution 1**:

Create an _AppStart.cshtml (C#)

```
@{
    SiteData.AdminEmail = "admin@mydomain.com";
}
```

**Solution 2**:

Create a static constructor in `SiteData` class

```
public static class SiteData
{
    public static string AdminEmail{ get; set; }
    static SiteData()
    {
        AdminEmail = "admin@mydomain.com";
    }
}
```

Both solutions initialize the `AdminEmail` at application start. Here are my questions:

1) Which solution is more appropriate in this situation?

2) Advantages and disadvantages of both solutions?

3) What is the use of AppStart in ASP.NET **IF** a static class can do its task?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell AppStart.cshtml seems much more integrated with the rest of the webapp. 
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior
A plain static constructor will have a lot less knowledge of the web environment

Answer (score 1):

Application level (global) variables can be defined using the `AppState` class in the Web Pages framework. This is a simple Dictionary similar to Session. You can also reference it by its dynamic alias: `App` e.g.

```
App.AdminEmail = "admin@mydomain.com";
```

is the same as

```
AppState["AdminEmail"] = "admin@mydomain.com";
```

You can intermix the two approaches.

The main disadvantage to using these is that they are not strongly typed. In a framework that relies largely on the `dynamic` type, that may not be an issue to you.

The main advantage is that AppState (or App) is really easy to use and does not require any additional plumbing to make it work.

The Web Pages framework is designed to reduce complexity for the developer. AppStart is just a simplified view of the Application_Start event handler in global.asax.